# "Hardly anything has changed." -- what is 'Hardly' used for here?

Tags: adverbs

> Hardly anything has changed.

The above format is common. However, I do not understand the role of 'Hardly' here.

According to [SpaCy](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=Hardly%20anything%20has%20changed.&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=0&cph=0) it is used as an adverb-modifier (advmod) of the main-verb: 'changed'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it like this:

> Not a lot of things have changed.

The word 'Hardly' is basically a part of the phrase 'Hardly anything'. It means the same as 'Not a lot of things'.

Note that the verb 'has' changes number in the process.

Comment: I would agree to "The word 'Hardly' is basically a part of the phrase 'Hardly anything'.". But, then, how can 'Hardly':adverb be used with 'anything':noun? -- That is the question.

Comment: Because as well as an adverb, _hardly_ is used as a modifier on the quantifier _any_. _Hardly any_ is a quantifier, just like _some_ and _three_. _Hardly anything_ is logically the same as _Hardly any thing_.

Comment: @ZeeshanAli "Anything" is not a noun, but a determinative. In your example the adverb "hardly" modifies "anything".

Comment: Oh! Right! "Anything" is not a noun, but a determinative (pronoun). Even so, an adverb cannot modify a pronoun either. I think @GaidinD explained it well that 'Hardly' has to do with the 'Any' of "Anything". Or, am I missing something?